# Adding Metadata tags to objects in S3 bucket using AWS Code Builder

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-codepipeline, aws-codebuild

I have a simple angular SPA project that is being hosted out of an AWS S3 buckets.

- The objects in the bucket require a few metadata tags (content-type, cache-control, etc) to make sure the content loads correctly and is updated frequently.
- I am using AWS code build to deploy the project to the S3 bucket with the following buildspec.yml file below:

```html
version: 0.2

phases:
  pre_build:
    commands:
      - echo Starting Build Now
      - npm install
  build:
    commands:
      - echo Build ready for manufacturing of the artifact
      - npm build
  post_build:
    commands:
      - aws s3 sync $BUILD_OUTPUT_LOCATION s3://$BUCKET_NAME --delete
      - echo Build completed successfully
```

Is there a command to have the necessary metadata tags added to the files being sync'ed in the S3 bucket in the post build of this buildspec.yml file?

Answer (score 1):

Use the parameter to add meta tag directly from aws cli, something like:

```
$ aws s3 cp s3://bucketname/ s3://bucketname/ --recursive --metadata-directive REPLACE --cache-control max-age=86400
```

#### - or -

```
$ aws s3 sync $BUILD_OUTPUT_LOCATION s3://$BUCKET_NAME --delete  --cache-control max-age=86400
```